# Integrating $\cos (x+\sin (x))$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I tried to solve $$\int\cos(x+\sin(x))\,dx$$ but it seems to be way out of my league (tried u-substitution with $u=x+\sin(x)$ and couldn't find an answer). Also, no one on the Internet seems to have tried this before and Wolfram|Alpha  and Symbolab aren't helping that much. If anyone can help me, I would apreciate it very much.

Comment: Maybe it does not have an anti derivative in terms of elementary functions...

Comment: @imranfat How could you prove that? and does one need high-level calculus knowledge to do it?

Comment: I concur with turrati. HOWEVER.......sometimes there are integrals that do have an anti derivative in terms of elementary functions and I have seen those ones...so do not put all of your trust into a computer algebra system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties) gives

$$ e^{ix\sin\theta}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}J_n(x) e^{ni\theta}\tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ e^{i\sin\theta+i\theta}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} J_n(1)\,e^{(n+1)i\theta}\tag{2}$$
and by considering the real part of both sides:
$$ \cos(\theta+\sin\theta) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} J_n(1)\,\cos((n+1)\theta)\tag{3} $$
so:
$$ \int\cos(\theta+\sin\theta)\,d\theta = \color{red}{C+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{J_{n}(1)}{n+1}\,\sin((n+1)\theta)}\tag{4} $$
where the RHS is a fast-converging series, since $J_n(1)$ behaves like $\frac{1}{2^n n!}$.
So, if you consider Bessel functions as elementary functions, **there is** a primitive in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Does Σ_{n ∈ Z} mean that the sum runs through all the integers (positives and negatives)?

Comment: @MassimilianoTron: yes. That can be simplified since $J_{-n}(z)=(-1)^n J_{n}(z)$.

Answer (score 3):

If you look in wolframalpha it says that this integral can not be expressed in elementary math functions, so the only way to express is the integral itself.

This is the wolfram result:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+cos(x%2Bsin(x))

If you want to know more about this kind of functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)

Comment: If we consider Bessel functions as elementary, my answer below proves that your first claim is wrong. Besides that, how WA told you that the primitive is non an elementary function? And what are *elementary functions* by WA's definition?

Comment: *Never* blindly trust Wolfram Alpha etc. about integrals and series. Often, they even do give a closed form with special functions, which can actually be simplifyed to an elementary (or at least "less special") one.